# Are these vectors a base of the Subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

$a=(1,2,3,0)$ $b=(0,3,2,4)$

$a$ and $b$ form the subspace $U$

is the base $B(a,b)$ a base of $U$?

My guess is yes, because they are linearly indpendent?

Comment: Correct answer.

Comment: what do you mean by charasteristic 0?

Comment: Please try and use $\LaTeX$ when posting on MSE. Just look at other posts for examples.

Comment: The charasteristic of a field is how many times you have to add $1$ to get $0$. And it is $0$ if you never get $0$. But since first component of $a$ is $1$ and the one of $b$ is $0$, the charasteristic doesn't matter.

Comment: @ajotatxe Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).